# Determine if set S is vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ defined in the following way:
$$S=\left\{A \in M_3 : \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\in R(A)\right\}.$$

Now I have to determine if this set is a vector space, but I am not really sure how am I supposed to do that, because I don't know what it means to have this matrix to be element of the image of matrix A (if we look at $A$ as linear operator, then, that matrix would be the element of codomain). How that can help me to determine if this set is vector space or not?

Comment: What is the first requirement of a subspace?

Comment: @hardmath i know, subset must have zero vector, and most likely, this is the set without zero vector, that is my assumption, but i don't know how to prove that since i don't understand problem completely

Comment: What is the "range" (column space) of the zero matrix?

Comment: @hardmath well, zero matrix has zeros at every position so span of all zeroes is zero

Comment: Check the notation used in your book, but $M_3$ is probably (real) $3\times 3$ matrices, and $R(A)$ is probably the column space of $A\in M_3$.  So you have the parts of an answer; you can just put it all together.

Comment: @hardmath $R(A)$ is set of all vectors of codomain that have their originals in the domain, i think that i should somehow look at this as matrix and not as linear operator i just don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you look at $A$ as a matrix or as a linear operator; it doesn't even matter whether $R(A)$ denotes the column space or the row space of a matrix $A$ or the range of a linear operator $A$; in any of these cases, the zero matrix/operator will not produce a non-zero vector, so this set doesn't have a neutral element with respect to addition, and hence it's not a vector space.

Comment: How do you know that zero matrix will not produce non zero vector in this case?

Comment: @cdummie: The zero matrix applied to any vector from either side yields zero, as does the zero operator applied to any vector. I'm not sure what you mean by "in this case" -- these are fundamental properties.

Comment: i mean that, in this case, i have the set of 3x3 matrices whose one element of image $R(A)$ is matrix 3x1 with elements 1 at every position. It seems that i don't actually understand what can i tell about matrix when i have one element of it's image given. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @cdummie: There may be various things that you can tell about the matrix, I don't know, I haven't thought about what else you can tell. All you need for the present problem is that the image/range of the zero matrix (or of the zero operator) contains only the zero vector, so whatever else you can tell about the matrix, you can certainly tell that it's not the zero matrix.